# How to use weekday_name function for day/month/year format of datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, weekday

I am trying to use Weekday function inside pandas to classify the actual dates with name of the day of the week but its not working. The format of my dates is `day/month/year`.

```
**My code**

data['date/time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Actual Pickup date/time'])
data['Day_of_Week_AP'] =data['date/time'].dt.weekday_name


Input data

Actual Pickup date/time
8/5/2018 16:39
5/6/2018 17:17
5/6/2018 17:17
5/6/2018 16:53
5/6/2018 16:53
5/6/2018 16:53
5/6/2018 16:53
5/6/2018 16:53
```

I am getting the below output which wrong .'8/5/2018' is tuesday and ' 5/6/2018 ' is also tuesday

```
Current Output 

Actual Pickup date/time Day_of_Week_AP
8/5/2018 16:39  Sunday
5/6/2018 17:17  Sunday
5/6/2018 17:17  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
5/6/2018 16:53  Sunday
```

How to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `dayfirst`

```
df['date/time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Pickup date/time'],dayfirst=True)
df['date/time'].dt.weekday_name
Out[814]: 
0    Tuesday
1    Tuesday
2    Tuesday
3    Tuesday
4    Tuesday
5    Tuesday
6    Tuesday
7    Tuesday
Name: date/time, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Rahulrajan `8/5/2018` this can be treat as m/d/y or d/m/y which may return back wrong outcome from pa.to_datetime, dayfirst pass a signal to the function  should be d/m/y